# How to create users with same email but with different in custom user attribute in Azure AD B2C?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I have to create multiple users in Azure AD B2C which only differs in a custom user claim.

Eg : I have an email '**test@gmail.com**' and also I have created a custom user attribute called as '**Project**' and then added this attribute in SignIn/SignUp user flow.
What I need is

**1)** To register the given email with differs in Project.
 ie;
 **User 1**
       email : 'test@gmail.com',
       project : 'Project1'

**User 2**
       email : 'test@gmail.com',
       project : 'Project2'

In the sign up flow I can create a user and can provide the specified attribute. But it doesn't allow me to create another account with the same email.

**2)** At the time of login user need to provide the '**Project**' as a second step of authorization.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is only one situation in Azure B2C that allows two users with the same email. That is one user is local account and another is social account. And this is what most people are avoiding. You cannot keep the same behavior for a local account and a social account. So I don't think it's possible currently.

Answer (score 0):

You can’t have two users with the same logon identifier. You could store the Project as an extension attribute, which would instead be a list.